# Figuring out how many bytes the HTTP server is sending to the client in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am using C.

Say a client sends a GET request to an HTTP server over a TCP connection using a connected socket:

```
"GET /path/file.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
```

The server should send to the client a header followed by the requested file. Unfortunately, the file is too big to be stored in a single buffer. So I want to instead read() from the sockID one buf[BUF_SIZE] at a time to store them into an output file. For that, I need the total number of bytes the server sent over sockID. This is where I am stuck... I tried the following to get the number of bytes:

```
struct stat st;
int err = fstat(sockID, & st);
if(err == -1)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "fstat: [errno %d] %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("size: %jd\n", st.st_size);
>>>> return: 0 bytes
```

I also tried:

```
lseek(sockID, 0, SEEK_END)
>>>> return: Illegal lseek
```

Finally, I looked into using getsockopt(), but after my best effort, I am still very confused on how this function is used.

What am I doing wrong? Is ther a much simpler solution to my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't seek on sockets (or most file types other than disks — these days, you don't have to worry about tape drives).  The information is embedded in the headers sent by the server, is it not?  So you need to read and parse the headers, and then read the actual data.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to know how big the file is in advance? `recv` returns the number of bytes received, isn't that the information you're looking for?

Comment: @tkausl: The problem is that if the code doesn't know how many bytes to expect, it won't know when the response is complete.  If the response is too big to fit in a single message, then you can run into problems.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you for your response. I tested recv. It returns the number of bytes read into the buffer, not the number of bytes sent by the server.

Comment: Just keep reading until EOF

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! I was able to get it using strstr()

Comment: @tkausl I can't because the file is 113MB long. I get segmentation faults if I try to store all of it in one buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do you know if there are any structures ready made for this kind of header parsing by any chance?

Comment: I'm sure there are — lots of people have written code to parse HTTP header information.  However, I'm not one of those people, and it isn't something I've needed, so I don't know what's a good library, I'm sorry to say.  (And asking for library recommendations is off-topic for SO.  You  could perhaps look on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and ask if you can't find an answer already there.)

Comment: The fact that the file is 113MB long does not prevent you from reading the socket until EOF. You need to read and write *in a loop*, stopping when EOF is received. You don't need a buffer the size of the file. However you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP, specifically the parts about content-length and transfer-encoding. You have some reading to do.

Comment: @EJP I can't possibly afford to test every character for EOF in the buffer at every loop though... My knowledge of the C libraries is VERY limited, but I am sure that any function that has to check for a specific character must be quite slow to run through a 113MB file. On the other hand, if I know the file length, I can just keep buffering the characters through in chunks, with only one thing to test for. BUT please correct me if I am wrong!!

Comment: There *is no* 'EOF character', and you therefore don't have to 'test every character for EOF in the buffer'. You have to check the *result of `recv()`* for EOF. See the documentation. You're just guessing as to how this works. Look it up.

Comment: @EJP this isn't always the case. HTTP requests and responses can be pipelined and the "keep-alive" feature will be used by most updated servers - meaning that no EOF will be sent until the connection times out. Parsing the "Content-Length" header (or handling chucked encoding) is essential for handling responses within a reasonable performance metric.

Comment: @Myst It is always the case that there is no EOF character, and that you have to check the result of `recv()` for EOF, not scan every character for it. The rest of your comment is exactly what I said in my answer. I am here addressing the OP's misconceptions as to how `recv()` and end of stream works.

Comment: @EJP - I mis-wrote, thank you. I know there's no EOF char (seeing as all byte values and sequences are valid in binary files, EOF can't be part of the file itself and it can't be any single byte value).

Comment: @RayaneCTX there are existing C libraries for HTTP, such as `curl` (client oriented library) and H2O of facil.io (server oriented libraries). If you need a parser, I think both the H2O parser and [the parser I wrote for facil.io](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/1437903de894a7f38b5fe3314fe2c543ea57f852/lib/facil/http/http1_parser.h) are MIT licensed (I'm not sure about H2O, but you can see for yourself).

Comment: @Myst See SteffenUlrich's comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to instead read() from the sockID one buf[BUF_SIZE] at a time to store them into an output file. For that, I need the total number of bytes the server sent over sockID.

No you don't. Trivially, you just need the canonical copy loop:

```
char buffer[8192]:  // or more, any size over zero will work
int count;
while ((count = recv(sockFD, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
{
    if (write(fileFD, buffer, count) == -1)
    {
        // write error
        perror("write()");
        break;
    }
}
if (count == -1)
    // terminated by receive error
    perror("recv()");
```

HOWEVER:

1. This will copy everything , including all the HTTP headers. You have to do more to read and parse those, and not write them to the file.
2. This won't work if the Transfer-encoding is chunked, and even if it isn't it will encounter a stall at end of stream until the server closes the connection, which it won't do immediately because of HTTP keep-alive. To counter that, you need to modify the loop to only read exactly as many bytes as were present in the Content-length header.

The solution to both is to either have a good read of RFC 2616 and successors, or else use an HTTP client library, which already does it all for you.

Comment: Nice answer but a small note: the OP is sending a HTTP/1.0 request without explicit `Connection: keep-alive`. Since keep-alive is only implicit with HTTP/1.1 and not explicitly given in this HTTP/1.0 request it means that the server will in this case close the connection immediately after the response is done. Also, chunked encoding is only defined with HTTP/1.1 so it will not apply in this case of a HTTP/1.0 request either.

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your answer! So if I understand correctly, there is not need to test for EOF directly. We only need to test the return value of recv(). I have an additional question though: In the recv() manual page, we have "If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer,
excess bytes may be discarded" How do you know this won't happen at each iteration of the loop here? Also, right after we have "If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait
for a message to arrive". Yet recv() still returns with count = 0, breaking the loop. Am I misunderstanding again?

Comment: @EJP I forgot to mention: your contrbution solved my problem, and I up-voted your response.

Comment: 1. Testing the return value *does* 'test for EOF directly'. There is no other test. Your notion of testing each character is simply mistaken. I've already explained that. 2. Truncation in `recv()` only applies to UDP.  You are using TCP. 3. `recv()` returns zero at end of stream. There is nothing to wait for.